# TestNG and Powermockito - cannot mock static void

Tags: java, testng, static-methods, powermock

I can't get Powermock work with TestNG. The same code adjusted to JUnit works fine, but somehow in TestNG it fails.
TestNG version is 6.8.21
Powermockito version is 1.6.1

```
package p;

import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;
import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;


import static org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.mockStatic;

@PrepareForTest({FooTest.class})
public class FooTest {

    @BeforeTest
    public void setup() {
        mockStatic(FooTest.class);
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        PowerMockito.doNothing().when(FooTest.class,"foo");
        FooTest.foo();

        Assert.assertEquals(1, 1);
    }

    public static void foo() throws Exception {
        throw new Exception("huh?");
    }
}
```

The exception I get is on the when method:

```
java.lang.Exception: huh?
    at p.FooTest.foo(FooTest.java:32)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.performMethodInvocation(WhiteboxImpl.java:1873)
    at org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.doInvokeMethod(WhiteboxImpl.java:773)
    at org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.invokeMethod(WhiteboxImpl.java:753)
    at org.powermock.reflect.Whitebox.invokeMethod(Whitebox.java:466)
    at org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.expectation.PowerMockitoStubberImpl.when(PowerMockitoStubberImpl.java:106)
    at p.FooTest.test(FooTest.java:25)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:85)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:696)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:882)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1189)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:124)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:108)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:348)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:343)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:305)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:254)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1224)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1149)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1057)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:111)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:204)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:175)
    at org.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:125)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.CommandLineWrapper.main(CommandLineWrapper.java:130)
===============================================
Custom suite
Total tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================
```

So what am I missing here?

Comment: OK, apart from the fact that you shouldn't mock static methods in the first place, I am not sure that you can `@PrepareForTest` your test class itself; have you tried and put that method in another class?

Comment: @fge Out of curiosity, what's so wrong with mocking static methods, when the need arises? In a real-world app, I recently had to mock a few of them (in the JSF `FacesContext` class and also in a class from JasperReports); if I were to not mock them, how else would I write the tests? Creating needless wrappers for `FacesContext` and JasperReports?

Comment: @fge, sure I did. This is just a minimized sample. And BTW, when I convert to JUnit it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this may be the same issue and solution as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35815153/993262).  In other words make sure you are using the `org.powermock.modules.testng.PowerMockObjectFactory`. But as @fge says, you should `@PrepareForTest` the class containing the static method(s) to mock, which should not be the test class itself...