# Generating TestNG.xml file from a simple "Hello World" code JAVA

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, testng

I configured my eclipse environment to generate a TESTNG.xml file.

My code has this:

```
package testMy;

    public class testMy {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            System.out.println("Hello!"); 
    
    }
        
    }
```

I installed TESTNG plugin and then i click on the project and selected option "convert to TESTNG"

[image]

I got this XML:

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "https://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite">
  <test thread-count="5" name="Test">
  </test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

Is it valid? I do not see any "Hello!" message or something like that inside of that?

Am i missing anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Conclusion First

### testng.xml

Add this under test

```
<classes>
  <class name="myTest.DemoTest"/>
</classes>
```

### Add unit test java DemoTest.java

## MyTest

```
├── pom.xml
└── src
    ├── main
    │   ├── java
    │   │   └── testMy
    │   │       └── testMy.java
    │   └── resources
    └── test
        ├── java
        │   └── testMy
        │       └── DemoTest.java
        └── resources
            └── testng.xml
```

### testMy.java

```
package testMy;

public class testMy {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
         System.out.println("Hello!"); 

    }
    public String echo(String msg) {
        return msg;
    }
    public String hello(String msg) {
        return "Hello "+msg;
    }
}
```

### testng.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<suite name="Suite" parallel="false">
  <test name="Test">
    <classes>
      <class name="myTest.DemoTest"/>
    </classes>
  </test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

### DemoTest.java

```
package testMy;

import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class DemoTest {
    private testMy theOne=null;
    @BeforeClass
    public void setUp() {
        theOne =new testMy();
    }
    


      @Test
      public void testEcho() {
          Assert.assertEquals("AAAA",theOne.echo("AAAA"));
      }
      @Test
      public void testHello() {
          Assert.assertEquals("Hello AAAA",theOne.hello("AAAA"));
      }

}
```

Comment: Hey pal, thank you for replying!
Could you please explain to me what you did in the code? Why did you created testEcho and testHello?

Comment: @programming_amazing most case, I am test class method , not static method , I add two method in your   testMy class (echo and hello) , In Test Class add testEcho and testHello. Or Your Question is How to Unit  Test static method ?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, pal. Could you please add static method aswell? Also, could you please tell me how the testng.xml is interpreted once processed in Jenkins or whatever?

Comment: @programming_amazing static method test, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29393773/testng-and-powermockito-cannot-mock-static-void

Comment: I don't understand how the XML will be interpreted.. will it read the <class name="myTest.DemoTest"/> and then it will seek for that particular class and execute it? how?

Comment: @programming_amazing , you can add second XXXTest.java , and add <class name="myTest.XXXTest"/> , guess , and write code , run test.